# Error while trying to perform isin while iterating

Tags: pandas

I have 2 data frames and I am trying to get the first value in the column 'name' of one dataframe & then do a isin using that value on the 'name' column of the other dataframe. I am trying to do it like this because, if isin is true, then i want to get the corresponding AGE and match both, then if that also is true, then get the corresponding City & match.

But i am getting the error as below. 
"TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]"
if I just print "row['name']", i get the value of first name but why is it not doing the isin check? what am i missing here?

```
Df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Marc', 'Jake', 'Sam', 'Brad'],
                'Age': ['24', '25', '26', '27'],
                'City': ['Agra', 'Bangalore', 'Calcutta', 'Delhi']})

Df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Jake', 'John', 'Marc', 'Tony', 'Bob', 'Marc'],
                'Age': ['25', '25', '24', '28','29', '39'],
                'City': ['Bangalore', 'Chennai', 'Agra', 'Delhi','Pune','zoo']})


for index, row in Df1.iterrows():
if Df2.name.isin(row['name'])==True:
    print('present')
```

Comment: Can you explain more, what you need? Because `iterrows` is slow, so possible another solution here.

Comment: actually i need to find the difference between these 2 dataframes. the out put should be a dataframe. given the above list the result dataframe should be Sam--26--Calcutta, Brad---27--Delhi,John--25--Chennai,Tony--28--Delhi, Bob--29--Pune & Marc--39--Zoo. If the Age is a number (here it is string) & the only difference i age (with name & city being same), i want to get the difference in age also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `isin` need lists, so possible solution is create one element list with [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) for test if at least one value matching - at least one `True`:

```
for index, row in Df1.iterrows():
   if Df2.name.isin([row['name']]).any():
        print ('present')
```

Or compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
for index, row in Df1.iterrows():
   if Df2.name.eq(row['name']).any():
        print ('present')
```

Comment: It worked. If there are more than i matching values, how to then loop them again? In other words how to get the count of matching values?

Comment: @mohanys - Use `count = Df2.name.isin([row['name']]).sum()`

Comment: one last question on this. how to find the index (row number) of the items that match? I tried  `Df2.name.eq(row['name']).loc` but got a statement that .loc indicator object was presnt but did not get the value itself.

Comment: @mohanys - Use `Df2.index[Df2.name.eq(row['name'])]`

Comment: oh boy! it worked but i am confused with the result. i got `Int64Index([2, 5], dtype='int64')
present
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
present, i was expecting only 2 & 5 because Marc was only at positions 2 & 5 in DF2. what is this zero? If you provide some material what i can look it up, i will do so. That would be sufficient. Any site where i can look into these complex items that would be fine also. Just started , so, lot of questions.

Comment: @mohanys - It means there is matched also `0`, depends of data. If starting in pabndas, check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html)